# How do I make the second inner section full width? Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I need to make a second full-width inside section (for the map), while keeping the width of the main section limited.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaezE.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Daw.png)

I tried to solve it with css, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a main section as a full-width then into inner section, you have to set margin from left side for left side content.[image]